# 12.10 403 Forbidden SymLink

Tags: 12.10, permissions, apache2, symbolic-link, virtualhost

I am trying to set up a simple development environment and even after setting all the permissions, I can't get past the 403 error

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I can access localhost but not the link:

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
<p><a href="workspace/sitepath">Site</a></p>
</body></html>
```

the `workspace` directory is a symbolic link.

Comment: Does apache have permissions to access the files that are symlinked?  check the ownership of the files/folder.

Comment: i added a+r permissions to the directories and checked everything. all permissions are set that i can tell.

Comment: What does apache error log state when you access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

When I installed the os, I must have ticked the encrypt my home folder box, not sure if this is really the issue but I'm sure it was no help.

I moved the workspace dir to `/var/www/` and everything is working.